# Best practice to import svg in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

I'm new to React native. I do the svg import as in the code below. But it doesn't looking well when it's too much. Is there a simpler way to do this?

```js
import React from 'react';
import LeftArrow from '../../assets/svgs/left-arrow.svg'
import RightArrow from '../../assets/svgs/right-arrow.svg'
import HeaderLogo from '../../assets/svgs/header-logo.svg'
import NotificationOn from '../../assets/svgs/notification-on.svg'


export default function SignUp() {

  return (
    <>
      <LeftArrow
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
      <RightArrow
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
      <HeaderLogo
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
      <NotificationOn
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

For example how can I use svg like this as I export and import images below

```js
// src/assets/images/index.js
export const woman = require('./woman.png'); 
export const signUp = require('./signup-bg.png'); 


// src/screen/SignUp.js
import { woman, signUp } from '../../assets/images/index.js'
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you mean when you say "doesn't hold up well when it's too much"? What specifically is happening, and under what circumstances? 

You should also consider posting code samples, rather than images. Source: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I corrected the content. I am trying to import svgs to any screen like I import images above.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`react-native-svg`](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) but you'll need the SVG file contents instead of bringing it in like an image.

Quick example:

```js
import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg`

const LeftArrow = (props) => {
 return (
   <Svg width={48} height={48} viewbox="0 0 48 48" {..props}>
     <Path d="something" fill="#00000" />
   </Svg>
 )
}

export default LeftArrow
```

but you could template the the file and bring in what you need from each SVG.